# PySpark performance difference while filtering using different techniques

Tags: python, pyspark

I understand we can filter PySpark data frames using a couple of different methods
Say if we have a data frame as below:

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *

>>> schema = StructType([StructField('A', StringType(), True)])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",), ("b",), ("c",)], schema)
>>> df.show()
+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
+---+
```

We can filter the column 'A' for a particular value in 3 different ways

```
df.filter(F.col('A')=='a') # using F.col()
df.filter(df['A']=='a') # using df['col_name']=='value'
df.where(F.col('A')=='a') #using .where
```

All three give the same results, but in case of large data sets with millions of rows, which one would be the best to use in terms of performance?

When I timed them in a Jupyter notebook cell, I could not get any conclusive results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All these are just the wrapper. Internally all go through same `spark sql` engine and would perform same.

Comment: Where is just an alias of filter